# Is it worthwhile to build native apps with Android Studio or XCode instead of focusing on React-Native?

Tags: android, react-native, native

I've read a lot of blog articles and did some research for our next step at our company. We have to decide, if we focus on developing our main app as a native app or use something as react-native or (even further away from native) hybrid-app like Ionic, PhoneGap.

There are so many articles and many of them had been written many years ago, and since then so much happend in the development.

What are the benefits of building native apps in 2018 instead of using hybrid apps?

Comment: Much more features with direct access (cross-platform = generalized). Stronger community & documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a new developer and went through a similar question myself for my first app I am building. I ended up choosing React Native for the following reasons:

1. the obvious cross platform win. Don't have to have separate teams and development for Android and iOS; removing a lot of cost, time and re-work and worry about parity. All code is in JavaScript instead of needing obj-c and Swift. If your company is interested in being in both mobile worlds, I imagine this will be the biggest factor. If you only are interested in one, then true native would be better. If you want to start with iOS for example and may move to Android later, I'd say React Native is better. You can still build and optimize for iOS and use the same code base when you want to start in Android.
2. React Native uses actual native components and tools and doesn't just emulate them through web like the hybrids
3. if some function or feature requires true Native to make it easier, you can bolt it on fairly easily.
4. allowed me to develop in windows or Mac environment

A link to a good review from ~6 months ago is https://codeburst.io/react-native-vs-real-native-apps-ad890986f1f